# How do I switch back from @gmail.com to @googlemail.com

Tags: gmail

I switched my Gmail account from `@googlemail.com` to `@gmail.com`, but now I can't post to mailing lists. Supposedly it can be switched back from the Accounts tab in Settings. But as the illustration shows, there is no appropriate option there. Where'd it go?

[Gmail by Google Accounts settings http://lh4.ggpht.com/_sUXm2cra4nQ/TD77l7uWSHI/AAAAAAAAABk/Dw9MQz1xuGA/s640/gmail-top.png](http://lh4.ggpht.com/_sUXm2cra4nQ/TD77l7uWSHI/AAAAAAAAABk/Dw9MQz1xuGA/s640/gmail-top.png)

Comment: I did find out how to switch back. And now I want a correct answer (from someone else) here!

Comment: (For reference:) [I changed my address to @gmail.com, but I want to change back to @googlemail.com.](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=159001):
No problem. You can change your address back to @googlemail.com by going to the "Accounts" tab under Gmail Settings and clicking the "Switch to@gmail.com?" link under "Send mail as:" (this link will only show up if you're eligible to change your address).

Comment: link: [Change Googlemail to Gmail](http://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/googlemail/rebrand)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It’s because the option to switch back from Gmail to Googlemail is only on the ‘Accounts and Import’ tab, not the ‘Accounts’ tab that is shown in the screen image. The ‘Accounts’ tab shown in the image is part of the older version Gmail user interface. If you click the ‘Newer Version’ hyperlink in the top right hand corner, then Gmail will show the ‘Accounts and Import’ tab in Settings and you’ll then be able to switch from Gmail to Googlemail (assuming that you had a Googlemail address in the first place).

Edit: Now that Tom has updated the original screen image to reveal the top of the window, it is clear that Gmail was running in Basic HTML View (as apposed to Standard View). Running in Basic HTML View is another reason why the ‘Accounts and Import’ tab doesn’t appear and therefore why the option to switch between @gmail.com address and @googlemail.com address doesn’t appear.

If you are running Gmail in Basic HTML View then you need to click the ‘Standard View’ hyperlink in the top right hand corner.

If you are running Gmail with the older version Gmail user interface then you need to click the ‘Newer Version’ hyperlink in the top right hand corner.

Having done both of those things if necessary, then the ‘Accounts and Import’ tab should be available within Settings to allow the option to switch between the @gmail.com address and the @googlemail.com address.

Answer (score 9):

There isn't a way within Gmail to switch your email address back across the board. However, you can work around this!

On the same settings page, "Add another email address": Enter your googlemail.com address here and save changes. After confirming (you should get a verification email, just click the link), you will see an option whenever you send an email to send from either your googlemail or gmail address.

An alternative is to unsubscribe and resubscribe to the mailing lists but this can be time consuming.

Comment: I'm sure it said when I switched not to worry because I could switch back.

Comment: From http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=159001
`You can change your address back to @googlemail.com by going to the "Accounts" tab under Gmail Settings and clicking the "Switch to@gmail.com?" link under "Send mail as:" (this link will only show up if you're eligible to change your address).`  
I guess perhaps you're not eligible for some reason? Maybe you're no longer registered as a UK address?

Comment: The only reason why the account would not be eligible to switch is if he wasn’t given a @googlemail.com address in the first place. That isn’t the case here, according to the question description. Some UK users were provided with a @gmail.com address, before the @googlemail.com address regime was introduced. Those users can’t switch between @gmail.com and @googlemail.com. Only users who were initially given a @googlemail.com address can freely switch between the two.